# Warum ist "bevorstehen" trennbar?

Tags: separable-verb, prefix

Mir ist bekannt, dass Verben mit dem Präfix "be" **untrennbar** sind, auch wenn ein anderes trennbares Präfix nach dem "be" steht, zum Beispiel: beabsichtigen, beauftragen, beeinflussen, beherbergen, bevorzugen...

Warum ist denn das Verb "bevorstehen" **trennbar**?

z.B. **Nun stehen Gabriel neue Auseinandersetzungen bevor.**

Gilt es als eine Ausnahme? Wenn Ja, gibt es Ihres Wissens ähnliche Verben?

Answer (score 7):

Das Präfix ist hier "bevor". Die meisten Verben, die mit "bevor" beginnen, haben das Präfix "be", z.B. "bevormunden". Doch das Verb "bevorstehen" ist ein Kompositum aus "bevor" und "stehen", und solche Komposita sind normalerweise trennbar. Daher ist "bevorstehen" eine Ausnahme.

Comment: Noch erwähnenswert: bevorzugen leitet demzufolge wohl von vorziehen ab, und ist damit eine Ausnahme von der Ausnahme

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich stimme Dir zu, wir meinen das gleiche :) - darum schrieb ich ja, dass es sich von "vorziehen" ableitet. Die Quintessenz für Lernende ist in jedem Fall: nur weil ein "bevor" gefunden wird, heißt es nicht, dass es auch ein "bevor" ist; es könnte auch ein "be-vor..." sein, was dann der Hauptregel mit be-... wieder folgt.

Comment: Woran kann man erkennen, dass das Präfix in _bevorstehen_ _bevor_ ist - außer eben gerade an der Tatsache, dass es trennbar ist?

Comment: Es gibt noch andere Bildung mit Präpositionen und -stehen: ab-stehen, ein-stehen, auf-stehen, durch-stehen usw. die ebenfalls getrennt werden. Insofern ist „bevor“, anders als „be“ eben auch eine Präposition.

Comment: @Ingmar Warum sind "bevormunden, bevorraten, bevorrechtigen, bevorteilen, bevorzugen" alle untrennbar?

Comment: Weil es hier um die Vorsilbe be- geht, und nicht -bevor: „vor“ ist bereits Teil des Stammwortes: Vormund, Vorrat, Vorrecht, Vorteil, Vorzug.

Comment: @Jonathan Scholbach: [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bevorstehen) gibt die "Wortzerlegung". Ich denke, der Grund dafür ist, dass "be- + vorstehen" eine andere Bedeutung haben würde. Auch der in Ingmars Kommentar genannte Grund.

Comment: Deine Regel "solche Komposita sind normalerweise trennbar" erscheint mir ein bißchen weit hergeholt - *bevormunden*, *bevorraten*, *bevorrechtigen* sind ähnliche Komposita, die untrennbar sind. Ich habe eher die Vermutung, dass die Trennbarkeit  bei *bevorstehen* mit dem Dativobjekt zusammenhängt.

Comment: @Ingmar *Vorstand*? - Das zieht irgendwie nicht.

Comment: @tofro: Aber "bevormunden" = "be-" +‎ "Vormund" + "-en", "bevorraten" = "be-" + "Vorrat" + "-en", "bevorrechtigen" = "be-" + "Vorrecht" + "-ig" + "en". Nur "bevorstehen" ist ein Kompositum aus vollständigen Wörtern. Andere solche Komposita: "beibringen", "fernsehen". "festsitzen", "feststellen", "großziehen", "hierbleiben", "klarkommen", "lahmlegen", "schiefgehen", "vollziehen", "wahrsagen", "wehtun".

Comment: @tofro: PS. "vollziehen" ist eine Ausnahme.

Answer (score 2):

Zuerst eine allgemeine Vorbemerkung zu Listen von trenn- und nicht trennbaren Verben: Solche Listen finden sich vor allem in Materialien zu "Deutsch als Fremdsprache" - Schüler an deutschen Schulen bekommen solche Listen im Allgemeinen nicht, ihnen wird allerhöchstens erklärt, dass es die Klassifikation gibt. Es wird erwartet, dass ihr "Sprachgefühl" ihnen zeigt, ob ein Verb trennbar ist oder nicht. Auch "offizielle deutsche Grammatikbücher" führen solche Listen i.A. nicht, sie sind also ein bisschen stiefmütterlich behandelt und möglicherweise nicht auf alle eventuellen Ausnahmen "abgeklopft".

Eine Eigenschaft, die ein Verb ziemlich sicher nicht trennbar macht, ist, wenn das Präfix kein eigenständiges Wort darstellt und deswegen nicht alleine stehen kann - deswegen finden sich Verben mit "be-, ent-, ver-" auf solchen Listen. "bevor-" ist durchaus ein gültiges deutsches Wort, das alleine im Satz stehen kann, und Verben mit "bevor-" sind deswegen mögliche Kandidaten für ein trennbares Verb. Trotzdem sind die Verben

- *bevormunden*
- *bevorzugen*
- *bevorraten*

und manche andere **keine** trennbaren Verben. Das liegt daran, dass die reine Buchstabenfolge "bevor" eben in sich schon ein Kompositum aus einem Präfix "be-" und einer Präposition "vor" sein kann.

"bevorzugen" ist aus "be-" und "Vorzug", "bevorraten" aus "be-" und "Vorrat" zusammengesetzt, während "bevorstehen" aus "bevor" und "stehen" zusammengesetzt ist und deswegen trennbar ist - das kann man leider nicht sehen, sondern nur wissen. Und es zeigt auch die Crux solcher Listen - sie sind fast nie vollständig und erfassen nicht unbedingt alle Ausnahmen.

Die Trennbarkeit von Verben kann man deswegen im Prinzip nur mit dem Verb zusammen lernen, leider stimmen solche Listen und Regeln eben nur **meistens**.